# How to separate two aqueous salts?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, purification

I have a mixture of two aqueous salts, $\ce{Cr(OH)3}$ and $\ce{NaNO3}$ and I'd like to separate them and purify the $\ce{Cr(OH)3}$ in order to make $\ce{KCr(SO4)12 . H2O}$ (Chromium Alum). Does any one know of a way to synthesize or separate out this compound?

Comment: Hydroxide is quite insoluble, so I wonder what's the problem here?

Comment: i have read that Cr(OH)_3 is one the few water soluble chromium compounds....

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium(III)_hydroxide No it isn't.

Comment: Chromium has quite a lot of water-soluble compounds, but this one is not among them.

Comment: Really? Maybe I added excess KOH, and it ended up dissolving. Perhaps i should do i dropwise addition of KOH to $Cr(NO_3)_3$?

Comment: Yes, that's the point.

Comment: The common way to synthesize chrome alum is the reduction of a sulfuric solution of potassium dichromate with ethanol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Physical method**

According to solubility rules, any nitrate salt is very soluble in water. Hydroxide salt are sparingly soluble in water. In particular, chromium hydroxide is insoluble in water. So, you can easily decant off the nitrate solution leaving behind chromium hydroxide.

**Chemical method**

Chromium hydroxide is amphoteric i.e. it reacts with both base and acid while sodium nitrate is not.

- As base

$$\ce{Cr(OH)3 + NaOH -> NaCrO2 + 2H2O}$$

$$\ce{Cr(OH)3 + 3NaOH → Na3[Cr(OH)6]}$$

- As acid

$$\ce{Cr(OH)3 + 3HNO3 → Cr(NO3)3 + 3H2O}$$

You can get back your chromium hydroxide from chromium nitrate by reacting with base and from sodium complex salt by reacting with acid.

Comment: Thanks guys. My problem was that i was not adding sufficient KOH to my solution, so it was not precipitating. I added a slight excess and it worked.